# Getting attempted to read or write protected memory error when getting CPUElapsedTimes using kernel32 Lib

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to get System Elapsed time. I am getting attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt error at this line (Info: It get value 0 for lcreationtime,lexittime,lkernaltime and lusertime)

```
If GetProcessTimes(lProcessID, lcreationtime.Value, lexittime.Value, lkerneltime.Value, lusertime.Value) Then
```

.NET API:

```
 Declare Function GetProcessTimes Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByRef lpCreationTime As Long, ByRef lpExitTime As Long, ByRef lpKernelTime As Long, ByRef lpUserTime As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GetSystemTimeAsFileTime Lib "kernel32" (ByRef lpFileTime As Long) As Long
```

I have created below Structures to convert values to Long.

```
Private Structure Cur64Math
Dim Value As Long     
End Structure

Private Structure Cur64Diff
Dim cLastValue As Cur64Math
Dim cLastDiff As Cur64Math
End Structure
```

And then the function that returns a string giving a difference is as follows:

```
Friend Function CPUElapsedTimes() As String
    Dim CreationTime, ExitTime As FILETIME
    Dim UserTime, KernelTime As FILETIME
    Dim CurrentTime As FILETIME
    Dim lcreationtime As Cur64Math
    Dim lexittime As Cur64Math
    Dim lusertime As Cur64Math
    Dim lkerneltime As Cur64Math
    Dim lcurrenttime As Cur64Math
    Dim lProcessID As Integer


    lProcessID = GetCurrentProcess

    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(lcurrenttime.Value)
    If GetProcessTimes(lProcessID, lcreationtime.Value, lexittime.Value, lkerneltime.Value, lusertime.Value) Then



            .cLastDiff.Value = lcurrenttime.Value - .cLastValue.Value
            .cLastValue.Value = lcurrenttime.Value


        GetElapsedTimes =  mFmtDiff(mUserTime.cLastDiff)


        'Here using Private mUserTime As Cur64Diff

    End If
Exit Function
```

Comment: The declaration is wrong.  First argument is IntPtr, return type is Boolean.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HansPassant . Its Worked by just changing first argument to type IntPtr.